# Bounded existential polymorphism

Tags: reference-request, lambda-calculus, type-theory, functional-programming, types-and-programming-languages

In his "*Types and Programming Languages*", Pierce, at the very end, presents the most powerful system in the book: $F^{\omega}_{<:}$. He, however, does not explain how bounded existential polymorphism would work. I could not find a reference to this online anywhere. Is this just not possible or just not very interesting or what? If this is possible could someone point me to a reference?

Comment: It seems like $(\exists x <: T. F) <: (\exists x <: S. F)$ if $T <: S$. I think more generally this should be include rules about the body of the type as well.